# Drupal 7 redirect to a specific page (a tab) after form submit

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm trying to redirect the page after i submited the form. The form is at the page     'formulaires/demande-de-subvention-pour-les-entraineurs' and i want to redirect to 'formulaires/demande-de-subvention-pour-les-entraineurs/entraineurs' How can i do this?

```
function ulsform_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'ulsform_demande_de_subvention_pour_les_entraineurs_form') {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'ulsform_demande_submited_form';
  }else if($form_id == 'ulsform_demande_de_subvention_pour_les_entraineurs_02_form'){
    $form['#submit'][] = 'ulsform_entraineur_submited_form';
  }
}

function ulsform_demande_submited_form(&$form, $form_state){
  global $user;

  $v = $form_state['values'];
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'formulaires/demande-de-subvention-pour-les-entraineurs/entraineurs';

/* My code to insert into the db */    


}
```

It doesn't work and when i try to create a form['#redirect'] like a saw on another post, it doesn't work too. What can i try?

Thank you for your help! I'm new to drupal

Comment: did the ans below work for you ?

Comment: Sure it did, that's why set it as the answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've forgotten to pass `$form_state` by reference, so your changes work only in the `form_alter` function.

Change your function signature as follows. Note `&$form_state`:

```
function ulsform_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
```

$form_state['redirect'] could be either an array or a simple string. 
if it's a string, user will be redirected there. 
If it's an array, it will work according to how [drupal_goto](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) works.

```
$form_state['redirect'] = array(
  'node/123',
  array(
    'query' => array(
      'foo' => 'bar',
    ),'fragment' => 'baz');
```

To `node/123?foo=bar#baz`

```
$form_state['redirect'] = 'node/123'
```

to `node/123`

Answer (score 0):

I have the following code in a custom module and after editing the content it is always redirect to /admin/content

```
function redirect_to_edit_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == "page_article_node_form") {
        $form['#submit'][] = "_redirect_to_edit";
    }
}

function _redirect_to_edit($form, &$form_state) {
    $form_state['redirect'] = array(
            'node/' . $form['nid']['#value'],
            array(
                    'query' => array(
                            'destination' => 'node/' . $form['nid']['#value'],
                    )
            )
    );
    dpm($form_state);

    drupal_set_message("L'article a été mis à jour.", 'status');
}
```

The query part I added as last try.
After the submission I can read my custom message but I can't make the user stays at the edit page.

What am I skipping?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Regarding https://www.drupal.org/node/1074616 and my experienced in the issue, there cases that redirection doesn't work. For me, I have achieved to make the desired redirection like this:

```
function redirect_to_edit_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == "page_article_node_form") {
        //$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = '_redirect_to_edit';
        $form['#action'] = '?destination=node/' . $form['nid']['#value'] . '/edit';
    }
}
```